# gRPC GetTransactionRequest

Tags: php, laravel, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am using dcrwallet from [here](https://github.com/decred/dcrwallet/blob/master/rpc/documentation/api.md) to get a transaction by hash.

```
$request = new Grpc\GetTransactionRequest(['transaction_hash' => 'my-hash-value']);

$response = $this->client->GetTransaction($request);
```

Where `GetTransaction` is a function that takes a `GetTransactionRequest` object. When I debug `GetTransactionRequest` in that function, it seems `GetTransactionRequest` does some kind of encoding to the transaction.

Is there any way I could avoid this or reverse the encoding?